# закрыть модальное окно после отправки формы

Tags: javascript, ajax, popup

```js
 $.ajax({
        url: '/addPhoto',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function() {
            $('.uploadPhoto').on('click', function() {
                $('.overlay').removeClass('visible');
                $(this).parents('.popup').removeClass('visible');
            });
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.error('Фото не сохранилось', error);
        }
    });
```

```html
<div id="popup-addPhoto" class="modal__content popup" role="document">
            <div class="modal__header">
                <div class="popup-close btn-close">&times;</div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal__body"></div>
            <%= typeof  msg != 'undefined' ? msg : '' %>
            <form  method="post" id="addPhoto" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                   <button type="submit" class="uploadPhoto btn">Отправить</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function() { $('.popup-close').trigger('click'); }
```

или

```
success: function() {
    $('.overlay, .popup').removeClass('visible');
},
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас слушатель клика висит на кнопке с классом .uploadPhoto, которого она не имеет.
uploadPhoto у вас почему-то прописан в type.

Comment: невнимательность. но оно все-равно не срабатывает